# XSLT Row Count Question

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, xslt

**Using XSLT v1.0**

*tl;dr : How do i count the number of rows where two columns contain non-null values?*

I have an application that records time stamps. I am taking two of those time stamps columns and finding the difference between the two times for each row. In some rows, there will not be a time stamp recorded for a column. This means that I may have only x amount of rows with both time stamps. I take all the time stamp differences, convert them to seconds and then add them up. I then want to divide them by the number of rows that have bot timestamps to get the average time.

I need a way to count only the rows that have valid time stamps in two columns.

I can count each row using :

```
<xsl:variable name="numRegOutNodes" select="count(/dsQueryResponse/Rows/Row/@Registration_OUT[string(.)])" />
```

And I can then use that to get an average usign this:

```
<xsl:value-of select="format-number((($sum div $numRegOutNodes) div 60), &quot;#,##0.00;-#,##0.00&quot;)"/>
```

But that ONLY is dividing by the number of rows that Registration_OUT is not null. I need the number of rows where Registration_OUT and Registration_IN are not null.

For example

```
<xsl:variable name="numRegNodes" select="count(rows where registration_out and registration_in are not null)" />
```

**Update**

I attempted to use the following :

```
 <xsl:variable name="numRegOutNodes" select="count(/dsQueryResponse/Rows/Row/@Registration_OUT[string(.)] & /dsQueryResponse/Rows/Row/@Registration_IN[string(.)])" />
```

per Vadims instruction. This did not yield any results and raised the question: is & an acceptable operator in XSLT? A question for another day I suppose.

Next I used :

```
Test : <xsl:variable name="numRegOutNodes" select="count(/dsQueryResponse/Rows/Row/@Registration_OUT[string(.)] and /dsQueryResponse/Rows/Row/@Registration_IN[string(.)])" />
```

No success.

I then used :

```
Test : <xsl:variable name="numRegOutNodes" select="count(/dsQueryResponse/Rows/Row/@Registration_OUT[string(.)] | /dsQueryResponse/Rows/Row/@Registration_IN[string(.)])" />
```

Which did not error out the webpart - and quite possibly could work. But why would the or operator work and not the and operator?

Thanks for paying attention. cheers

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The following expressions could be specified in order to get the number of rows where:

a) `Registration_OUT` **AND** `Registration_IN` are not null:

```
 <xsl:param name="numRegOutNodes" select="count(/dsQueryResponse/Rows/Row[@Registration_OUT[string(.)] and @Registration_IN[string(.)]])"/>
```

b) `Registration_OUT` **OR** `Registration_IN` are not null:

```
<xsl:param name="numRegOutNodes" select="count(/dsQueryResponse/Rows/Row[@Registration_OUT[string(.)] or @Registration_IN[string(.)]])"/>
```

P.S. Code samples have been tested in SPS 2010

Comment: This was my original attempt, although I used "and" as opposed to "&". Either way fails to work - both cause a correlation ID to appear. Thanks for trying.

Comment: Seppuku, the answer has been updated

Answer (score 0):

The following should work. You have to play with the code to get it work. just make sure it's formatted this way column_Name[text()]

count(registration_out[text()])

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I appreciate it. However the question is really about how to format a count for all rows that are empty for BOTH Registration_OUT and Registration_IN at the same time. I can get counts for both of them individually no problem. For example : count(number of rows where registration_out OR registration_in are not empty). I've tried quite a few different permutations and haven't made any progress. Thank you for your time, I truly appreciate it.